Can I install Windows 10 (64 bit) on my old computer with Intel Core 2 Duo 2.40ghz/2M/800/e4600?
That is my CPU. It is an Intel Core 2 Duo 2.40ghz/2M/800/e4600.
Can you please check if it can run Windows 10 (64 bit) or not?


I googled "intel e4600" and information was given - did you try that?

Aside from my answer, that box seems like a good candidate for a light linux install, which might be a better option here. Also, that seriously needs a clean

Your processor does support Windows 10 22H2 processor requirements, this isn’t a soft requirement, it’s a hard requirement preventing Windows from even booting

I did an install of Windows on a laptop with a roughly contemporary processor years ago. I'd note that the 'free' update path to Windows 10's ended, and I don't really think its worth buying a licence for something this old when a 'modern' very low end NUC class box dosen't cost much more and would get you the same performance.
That said, you would want to maximise the ram - IIRC these ran DDR2, which you might be able to get cheap. 2gb is a minimum (and run 32 bit), 4gb is preferred. You would also want to run a SSD, not a traditional HDD as a boot drive. Both of these compensate for the slower processor a little.
In a sense it'll run but poorly, and the upgrades needed to get the system to an acceptable level of performance - for a 15 year old system, as well as the cost of the OS licence means there's probably no point.

AS a n experiment I recently installed Windows 10 64 bit on a 2007 Dell D-830 laptop (2.4 GHz Core 2 Duo, 2 GB RAM). I replaced the HDD with an SSD and it ran surprisingly well. I didn't buy a Windows license ;-)

I'd updated mine to windows 7, and well, that came with a windows 10 update free. The laptop eventually died of old age, and dad decided to finally upgrade after a decade or so of using that laptop so I can't really test it. Still looking at the condition of the PC, I'm just a little iffy about it.
